# Return some of the members in the array, according to a given index array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new here on the site, I have a question in javascript.

I have 2 arrays:
First array - contains the members I have.

```
[
{prefer: "code_react", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "code_css", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "code_angular", rating: "5"},
{prefer: "code_html", rating: "5"},
{prefer: "sport_soccer", rating: "5"},
{prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "sport_running", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "5"}
]
```

Array Two - Contains the indexes I need to return in the first array.

```
[4, 6, 5, 7]
```

i want to return

```
[
{prefer: "sport_soccer", rating: "5"},
{prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "sport_running", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "5"}
]
```

I want to do it while running o (n) I thought to do it in brute-force but it is not effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, You want `O(n)`. So I loop over the indexes which takes `O(n)` and accessing takes `O(1)` and adding into the result array takes `O(1)`. So overall `O(n)`

```js
const source = [
  { prefer: "code_react", rating: "3" },
  { prefer: "code_css", rating: "3" },
  { prefer: "code_angular", rating: "5" },
  { prefer: "code_html", rating: "5" },
  { prefer: "sport_soccer", rating: "5" },
  { prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "3" },
  { prefer: "sport_running", rating: "3" },
  { prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "5" },
];

const indexes = [4, 6, 5, 7];

const result = [];
indexes.forEach((el) => {
  result.push(source[el]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the second array:

```js
const array1 = [{
    prefer: "code_react",
    rating: "3"
  },
  {
    prefer: "code_css",
    rating: "3"
  },
  {
    prefer: "code_angular",
    rating: "5"
  },
  {
    prefer: "code_html",
    rating: "5"
  },
  {
    prefer: "sport_soccer",
    rating: "5"
  },
  {
    prefer: "sport_swimming",
    rating: "3"
  },
  {
    prefer: "sport_running",
    rating: "3"
  },
  {
    prefer: "sport_tennis",
    rating: "5"
  }
];

const array2 = [4, 6, 5, 7];

const result = array2.map(index => array1[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result I would `.sort()` the numbers array first.
`const indexes = [4, 6, 5, 7].sort((a, b) => a - b);`
Create an empty array. `result = []`
And use `indexes.forEach(el => result.push(initialDataArr[el]))` to add the desired elements to the array.